# Is this function template specialised or not?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
template<class Y>
struct Foo
{
    void bar(std::vector<Y>);

    template <class T>
    void bar(std::vector<T>);
};
```

What is the relationship between the two member functions? Is one a specialised form of the other? I'm reluctant to say so since the first one is already "sort of specialised" on the `Foo` type instance.

What would happen if `T` and `Y` were the same?

Comment: It looks like plain and simple overloading.

Comment: "what would happen..." -- show us a full example about which you have doubts.

Comment: Unusually for you, this question is not well articulated. Can you improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bar` is just an overloaded function in your example. If `Y` and `T` are the same then overload resolution will pick `void bar(std::vector<Y>)` as it is not a function template.

Answer (score -1):

```
foo<int> fi;

vector<int> vi;
vector<float> vf;

fi.bar(vi); // overload #1 gets chosen (more specialized for T=int)
fi.bar(vf); // overload #2 gets chosen
```